# Android library to dynamically list classes contained in a downloaded DEX file

Tags: android, library

Let's say my Android app downloads a DEX file from a remote server, in order to use the classes contained within.

Loading a class from a DEX file is easy if I know the class name (including namespace of course).

But how to dynamically find out what classes are contained in the DEX file?

- I am pretty sure the Android API does not have anything for this.
- DEX2JAR can do it, but it is a rather big library that does many things, I want a much lighter library.

Requirements:

- Takes DEX file path, returns list of classes
- Open source, usable in a GNU-GPLv3 project.
- Extremely light. That's the main criteria, more important than speed.